# Query SSH inbound source 0.0.0.0/0 used in ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssh, aws-cli

I would like to query and list all ec2 instances that have a rule allowing source = 0.0.0.0/0 (inbound) to ec2 instances on port 22/ssh.

The goal is to get a list with all servers that have a rule allowing anyone to hit the server on port 22/ssh. I need to review and see all server in this situation to apply the right hardening.

Is that possible? How can I have control, visibility = Governance about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that:

- Retrieves a list of security groups
- Loops through the security groups and checks the Inbound rules
- Checks for SSH `0.0.0.0/0`

It's probably easier to write in a language like Python rather than using the AWS CLI unless you are particularly good at shell scripts.

It would be something like this:

```
import boto3

PORT = 22
ANYWHERE = '0.0.0.0/0'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

groups = ec2.describe_security_groups()

for group in groups['SecurityGroups']:
    for permission in group['IpPermissions']:
        if 'FromPort' in permission and PORT >= permission['FromPort'] and PORT <= permission['ToPort']:
            for range in permission['IpRanges']:
                if range['CidrIp'] == ANYWHERE:
                    print group['GroupName']
```

See: [`describe_security_groups()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups)

You could also create an [AWS Config rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config.html) that can continuously check for configuration violations.